# Cannot resolve some classes in xml file and get red tag like TextView, FrameLayout and all tags that isn't androidx

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

i did clear project and rebuild, i did invalidate cache and restart, i did remove .idea folder and all of these things did't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried re syncing gradle build

Comment: Sure i synced it 10 times :( , i have this problem only in one of my projects not in all.

Comment: kindly, show complete xml code.

Comment: Delete `.idea` file and `.gradle` files(folders) and try to sync the gradle again

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your parent layout contains these lines or not!

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

I was also getting this issue but I added the missing line from above and I resolved my issue. Please also check your layout file tags opening and proper closing. Thank you!

Comment: i checked this, your problem is normal and IDE tell that to add xml namespaces, but my problem is different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upgrade your gradle I faced the same issue, I resolved my issue by upgrading gradle plugin in project level build.gradle file from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
```